# I can't get IIS to show detailed errors in the response page

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I believe that my .net Core app is throwing an exception. IIS refuses to show anything else than:

HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start

Setup:

- In IIS/Error pages/Edit Feature Settings I have chosen "Detailed errors".
- In startup.cs/Configure I have UseDeveloperExceptionPage, and also tried removing it.

Should be an obvious thing, making IIS show the errors from the app when developing.

Anyone know if there are more settings that is needed?

Comment: Not sure I'm totally spot on but I believe any settings you change apply to the internals of how ASP.Net functions, however the error implies ASP.Net did not start. Not sure if you have any control over this specific type of error.

Answer (score 0):

To enable detailed error for iis asp.net core site you can follow this steps:

1. Make sure you have set the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to "Development" In Startup.cs:
2. Enable detailed error message in iis:
   Open IIS Manager, select your website
   Double-click on the "Error Pages"
   Click "Edit Feature Settings" on the right-hand side.
   Choose "Detailed errors" and click "OK."
3. Add this code in your web.config file:

<aspNetCore ... stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess">

The hostingModel attribute should be set to either "InProcess" or "OutOfProcess" depending on your hosting configuration.

Create a folder named "logs" in the root directory of your ASP.NET Core application.

assign iis_iusrs and iusr full control permission to the log folder.

Make sure you have installed .net core hosting bundle.

You can try running your application from the command line using the dotnet CLI to see if you can get more detail about the error or not